# Nodejs Pagination of API Call Using Offset

Tags: node.js, pagination, offset

I apologize if this question is documented already, please point me to those resources.

I have a nodejs app making an api call to Untappd and per most public APIs, I'm restricted to a max number of items returned in the call, in this case 50 is the max. I'd like to set up the pagination using Offset (Skip) so that I could move through the 600+ items instead of just the 50.

**What Works**
I currently have the pagination working to view the first 50 items through these different pieces...

**API call on server.js**

```
const untappdAPI = { method: 'GET',
url: 'https://api.untappd.com/v4/user/beers/username',
  qs: 
   { access_token: 'abc123'
    ,limit:'50'
     }    
  };
```

**app.get with pagination on server.js**

```
app.get('/untappd', function (req, res) {
  try {
    request(untappdAPI, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        const untappdBeers = JSON.parse(body);
        const utBeerList = untappdBeers.response.beers.items.map(item => item );
//pagination
const perPage = 5;
let currentPage = 1;
const totalBeerList = utBeerList.length;
const pageCount = Math.ceil(totalBeerList / perPage);

if(req.query.page) {
  currentPage = parseInt(req.query.page, 10);
}
const start = (currentPage - 1) * perPage;
const end = currentPage * perPage;
        res.render('untappd.ejs', {
          utBeerList:utBeerList.slice(start, end),
          perPage: perPage,
          pageCount: pageCount,
          currentPage: currentPage,
        });
    });   
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Something went wrong", e)
  }
  });
```

And then the items render on a page called untappd.ejs and the working pagination is provided with this code

**EJS Client Pagination on untappd.ejs**

```
<div id="pagination">
<% if (pageCount > 1) { %>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <% if (currentPage > 1) { %>
            <li><a href="?page=1">&laquo;</a></li>
        <% } %>
        <% var i = 1;
        if (currentPage > 5) {
            i = +currentPage - 4;
        } %>
        <% if (i !== 1) { %>
            <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        <% } %>
        <% for (i; i<=pageCount; i++) { %>
            <% if (currentPage == i) { %>
                <li class="active"><span><%= i %> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
            <% } else { %>
                <li><a href="?page=<%= i %>"><%= i %></a></li>
            <% } %>

            <% if (i == (+currentPage + 4)) { %>
                <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
            <% break; } %>
        <% } %>
        <% if (currentPage != pageCount) { %>
            <li><a href="?page=<%= pageCount %>">&raquo;</a></li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
<% } %>
</div>
```

Again, the above code is all well and good, I get functioning pagination with 5 items per page and 10 pages to paginate through, but I am limited to these 50 items. From what I've read about offset, it seems offset would allow me to cycle through the entire set of 600+ items, but I can't find documentation/help that fits this particular scenario.

How do I incorporate 'offset' into what I'm working with in order to paginate through the full list of 600+ items?

Many thanks for your help!

Red

Comment: but [the documentation](https://untappd.com/api/docs#beersearch) says you can pass parameters such as `offset` and `limit`... if you want to get the beers from 0 to 50 then `offset: 0, limit: 50` if you want from 51 to 100, then `offset: 50, limit: 50`, and so on... why aren't you passing that info to the query? and why the `.map(item => item)`? makes no sense 

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://untappd.com/api/docs#beersearch) is quite straight forward (UNLESS you are trying something else... but I'm assuming `/v4/search/beer`), all you need to do is use the `offset` and `limit` that the API provides, that would work like:

> ```
> offset (int, optional) - The numeric offset that you what results to start
> limit (int, optional) - The number of results to return, max of 50, default is 25
> ```

this means that

- if you want to search beers from 0 to 50, set: `offset: 0, limit: 50`
- if you want to search beers from 51 to 100, set `offset: 50, limit: 50`
- if you want to search beers from 101 to 150, set `offset: 100, limit: 50`

I would change your code as:

```js
const untappdAPI = (name, currentPage, perPage) => ({ method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.untappd.com/v4/search/beer',
  qs: { 
    q: name,
    access_token: 'abc123',
    limit: perPage, // 50
    offset: currentPage * perPage  // 0*50 = 0 | 1*50 = 50 | 2*50 = 100
  }    
})
```

having that as a function, will allow you to simply pass parameters such as

```js
app.get('/untappd', function(req, res) {

  const { search, currentPage, perPage } = req.query
  const url = untappdAPI(search, currentPage, perPage) // (currentPage - 1) if you start with 1

  try {
    request(url, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) throw new Error(error)

      const apiRes = JSON.parse(body).response
      const beers = apiRes.beers.items
      const total = apiRes.found // outputs in the API, first item in the response

      res.render('untappd.ejs', {
        utBeerList: beers,
        perPage: perPage,
        pageCount: Math.ceil(total / perPage),
        currentPage: currentPage,
      })
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Something went wrong", err.message)
  }
});
```

The only thing left to do, is update the HTML, as you can see from the call, we need 3 parameters (you can make some static and do not give the user the option to change, for example, items per page, and always display 50 at a time...

```html
<a href="?page=<%= pageCount %>&currentPage=<%= currentPage %>&perPage=50">&raquo;</a>
```

---

**Note**

in your code, you are outputting `const pageCount = Math.ceil(totalBeerList / perPage);` but the API response gives you the total items that can be retrieved in the first item in the documentation response as the `found` variable

---

**P.S.** I've request access to the API to verify if all this works, I will update the answer soon I have a client id and a secret

Comment: This is great, thank you so much balexandre, I've updated the actual url, the url being used is: https://api.untappd.com/v4/user/beers/username. I am receiving an error, `res.render('untappd.ejs', {  TypeError: res.render is not a function`, but perhaps when you've received your id and secret you'll see a similar error?

Comment: Ok the above mentioned error is gone because I updated your code from this...
`const res = JSON.parse(body).response
const beers = res.beers.items
const total = res.found` to this I replaced **res** with a different variable name `const untappdBeer = JSON.parse(body).response
      const beers = untappdBeer.beers.items
      const total = untappdBeer.found`. Please let me know if this change was a good move.

Comment: Current Status: I've replaced my original html on untappd.ejs of `<a href="?page=<%= pageCount %>">&raquo;</a>` to your HTML suggestion of `<a href="?page=<%= pageCount %>&currentPage=<%= currentPage %>&perPage=25">&raquo;</a>`. The result is that I see a list of 50 items on the page (not sure I want that many at once), but there is no pagination displaying at the bottom of the page to paginate through the entire 600+ items.

Comment: my bad, should be `apiRes` instead of `res`... writing code on StackOverflow without ESLint does that  regarding your pagination issue, the docs for the route you mentioned actually have no `found` but have `beers.count` that I do not know if it's the amount returned or amount found... just need to test... find me on Discord as balexandre#5711 and I might able to help if you send me the hole JSON returned...